# How to send fax using lotus notes through C# domino.interop.dll

Tags: interop, lotus-notes

I am sending fax using c# (domino.interop.dll). In my specific scenario if a particular fax fails to deliver then the fax delivery mail should be triggered. Is there any option to set the fax delivery report?

How can I do that in c# ?

FYI,

I am referring to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29442/Send-Lotus-Notes-Email-Using-C  except the fax address is different.

Comment: it doesn't appear there's a way to control what that fax delivery report looks like - is that what you're asking?

Comment: Just like a mail delivery report in lotus notes.You will recieve a delivery failure mail if the mail gets failed to send.Same way I need to trigger that programmaticaly.